# Text installer freezes at the language selection panel on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (UEFI)

Tags: system-installation, uefi, 64-bit, 16.04, usb-drive

I just downloaded the newest version of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)
and created a USB UEFI boot media (with Rufus 2.8).

The boot is going fine, but when I press "install ubuntu server",
I get stuck on the first panel (language selection).

I read, that the possible error could be the USB keyboard,
so I tried a different keyboard, but the problem still exists.

Then after some trial and error, I went under "check disk failures"
and this error message appears: **"Error while running 'modprobe -v usb-storage'"**

Is there a problem with the brand new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AMD64 image when it is installed in UEFI mode?

**edit:** So I tried the same iso in a VM, and the VM installation was a success. Next, I am going to use another USB Stick for installation.

**edit2:** new USB Stick -> same problem.

Comment: You say you "get stuck," but it's not clear what the problem is. Please elaborate.

Comment: the screen is "frozen", keyboard inputs don't get processed at all.

Comment: Also, what you've got is still not 16.04 GA; it's a very late release candidate.

Comment: well, i already thought about that, i will check if the checksum is identical with the images that is going to be released in a few hours. (the image i used is (ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso 20-Apr-2016 23:00  655M)

Comment: so i checked the "new" GA image, and its identical, with the one i used.

Comment: Then I recommend you [file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I just tried with Ubuntu 15.10 and get the same.

Comment: nope, was not able to resolve this problem, switch to good old BIOS installation and skipped UEFI for now, because it was time critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have the same problem. I solved it by disabling SecureBoot in my BIOS settings. I have ability to disable SecureBoot and keep enabled UEFI. Some guys on other forums use legacy bios.
[I use rufus 2.8 and follow settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSqZW.png)